# UITableView animation doesn't work after adding a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Literally! Can't understand why. Here's my code guys:

```
_tableOne_cloned = [_tableOne mutableCopy];

[_tableOne_cloned setFrame:CGRectMake(-320.0f, [_tableOne frame].origin.y, [_tableOne frame].size.width, [_tableOne frame].size.height)];

[[self view] insertSubview:_tableOne belowSubview:_bottomActionBar];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 animations:^{
    [_tableOne setFrame:CGRectMake(-320.0f, [_tableOne frame].origin.y, [_tableOne frame].size.width, [_tableOne frame].size.height)];
}];
```

The thing is simple: I have an UITableView on my screen. When I push a certain UIButton, the UITableView must disappear and another one will appear from the left.

But, this is not working. If I delete the line where I'm adding the new table works perfectly.

NOTES: UITableView doesn't conform NSCopying protocol but I created an extension to support it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why copy? why not create another new UITableView and try displaying it..

Comment: Ow, sorry I didn't explain it... I'm coding some kind of "simulated-carousel" and I don't want to collapse the memory with tons of UITableViews not in use. So I decide to clone the one I need and, after animations, set one to nil

Comment: `mutableCopy` invokes the `mutableCopyWithZone:` method which is defined in the `NSMutableCopying` protocol, not the `NSCopying` protocol. That function is really only for classes that have a mutable and immutable version, such as `NSArray`. Have you tried just using `[_tableOne copy]` instead?

Comment: Seems to have the same behavior for mutableCopy or copy...

Comment: So why are you creating an extension to support mutable copying for a class that doesn't really ask for that implementation? Secondly, why use `copy`? Why not load from Nib each time or just make a method that inits and returns a completely set up `UITableView`?

Comment: Because I need a copy of UITableView in order to generate the effect desired. Here's an (awful) drawing: http://awwapp.com/s/fc/26/24.html. Anyway the cloned object is created correctly

Comment: I think I understand what you want, I just don't know if making a custom implementation of `NSCopying` is necessary. I don't know if that's where the issue is, but it seems to be introducing unnecessary complexity. Why not load from Nib each time or just make a method that inits and returns a completely set up `UITableView`?

Comment: 'Cause there's some animations that must be done. And I want to have just one UITableView at time, for memory issues. The idea is, when animations complete, set to nil the original table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30918/discussion-between-maarten-and-yoryo)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to animate it from left

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 animations:^{

    [_tableOne setFrame:CGRectMake(-320.0f, [_tableOne frame].origin.y, [_tableOne frame].size.width, [_tableOne frame].size.height)];

}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     [_tableOne setFrame:CGRectMake(+320.0f, [_tableOne frame].origin.y, [_tableOne frame].size.width, [_tableOne frame].size.height)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 animations:^{
        [_tableOne setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, [_tableOne frame].origin.y, [_tableOne frame].size.width, [_tableOne frame].size.height)];
    }];

}];
```

Comment: Well, I use -320.0f value on x origin because I want the UITableView animate out of the screen. At the beginning of animation it's 0.0f

Comment: ok then make it reverse and apply it with that tableview which one you want set at 0.0f

Comment: Yep, but this is the weird behavior I'm experimenting... didn't work

Comment: Hi Yoryo, what you really want to do? Are you want to animate your table from 0.0f to -320.0f and again want to animated it with is's same position then please try my updated code. And if any query still pending then please ask it?

Comment: If you see my code above, you can note that I have, in origin, one UITableView, with coordinate x on 0.0f. When I push one button, I clone it, but the cloned one have its coordinate x on -320.0f. So we have two UITableViews. At this moment I want to animate both of them, the first one to coordinate x on 320.0f and the cloned one to coordinate x on 0.0f. And finally destroy the original UITableView.

Comment: mutableCopy doesn't work with UITableview so u need to reload the same tableview and animate the same table from left to right or right to left whatever u want. So it not Use your memory allocation again and again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30912/discussion-between-chandan-and-yoryo)